# React-Native Tab Navigation drawer navigation how to hide tabbar and header for every screen v6

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-tabnavigator

Trying to hide header and tabbar in Tab navigation in v6

```
<Tab.Screen
   name="LoginScreens"
   component={LoginStackScreen}
   options={{tabBarVisible: false}}
 />
```

But here **tabBarVisible** is not working

Answer (score 0):

After researching found the solution which is different from v5

```
   <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="LoginScreens"
        component={LoginStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'},
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

tabBarStyle: {display: 'none'} to hide the tabbar and headerShown: false is to hide the header for all pages